# Shadow outer variable inside block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
variable = 1
```

And a block that is using the same name variable:

```
[*1..10].each do |n|
  ...
  variable = 2
end
```

Is there a way to avoid changing the outside variable (shadow?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Since Ruby 1.9, Ruby introduced block-local variables that any variable precedes with `;` will not be affected. But this is not good, please consider using another name in the block.

```
variable = 1
[*1..10].each do |n; variable|
  ...
  variable = 2
end
```

Comment: But even if I do not put `;` it still remains. Try out this `variable = 1
[*1..10].each do |n,variable|

      variable = 2
end

puts variable`

Comment: The use of a semi-colon to define block local variables is evidently is not very popular as I've *never* seen it used (and didn't know about it until now). I don't know if I'd counsel others to not use it, however, as the Ruby monks decided it was a worthwhile addition.